# Record type arrays

Tags: c#, .net-core

So this is returns `true` in C#

```
var car1 = new Car(5, new Wheels(4));
var car2 = new Car(5, new Wheels(4));
Console.WriteLine(car1 == car2);

public record Wheels(int count);
public record Car(int seats, Wheels wheels);
```

But this doesn't:

```
var car1 = new Car(5, new[] { new Wheel() });
var car2 = new Car(5, new[] { new Wheel() });
Console.WriteLine(car1 == car2);

public record Wheel();
public record Car(int seats, Wheel[] wheels);
```

Of course I could define my own type like `RecordArray : IEnumerable` with overridden Equals  & operators where I compare the values (and optionally their order), but is that **the** way?

I'm asking because this solution feels "dirty".

Comment: Your second example is using arrays and they are reference type, so they are not going to be equal.

Comment: "but is that the way" -- yes, or you can override `Car`'s `public virtual bool Equals(Car other)` method and provide your own equality implementation

Comment: implementing `IEnumerable` when you actually want to check for equality? No, definitly not the way to go. You may search for "implementing equality for custom type in C#", though.

Comment: How about just use a `List<Wheel>`?

Comment: @Sweeper No difference

Comment: You need `SequenceEquals` to compare two containers based on their contents.

Comment: @canton7 But can I? IntelliSense only shows GetHashCode() and ToString() as overrideable on the record itself

Comment: @Doidel it's not a matter of overriding. If you specify your own comparison operator the compiler won't create its own

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh, that works? Can you write this comment as an answer so I might accept?

Comment: A very interesting question! It *appears* that there is no variable-size collection data structure in .NET whose comparison behavior defaults to *structural* rather than referential equality, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. (For fixed size, both ValueTuple and Tuple should work.)

Comment: Intellisense doesn't know some things about records, annoyingly. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgL8BmAAiNoHUALGGAG1oG9aBfCqnViQoGWgGEAhlAAUASwB2AF1oBnGJKWq0TVhwDaAXVoB3Pe1UBKClwq179OgDc5UJQFdJnYBAicAogCOnhYyUlC0EEqsUNbkDtx2CQ7RUBAmtAru7OwA3En2/JTxDjSRTjBQUHIYMLSKKgDiMEoAEpKqzOIQtTJxCbYlybSp6ZnZeQV8FLxAA)

Comment: I found a duplicate and linked your question to it. It appears that your idea to create a custom collection type is in fact the canonical solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, all else being equal, the `==` for reference types compares using reference equality. That is, two items are equal only if they refer to the same object in memory, at the same address. But `record` is special. When comparing records using `==`, they compare using value. That is, the value of each property is compared between the two items.

Both examples are therefore doing a value-equality comparison. And in both cases, the `seats` property matches up. It's the `wheels` property that's different. So let's look there.

In the first example, `wheels` is another record. We're doing a value comparison, and so we see this is a `Wheels` record. This in turn looks inside each `Wheels` object to make sure the properties match. They do, so the result is `true`.

In the second example, we are still doing a value comparison, but now we have a  `Wheel[]` instead of a `Wheel`. Regardless of whether they contain a value type, reference type, or record, arrays themselves **are reference types**. When the record value-comparison reaches this point it is still doing a value comparison... but because this property member is a reference type it will **compare the value of the references**.

In other words, those two arrays can only be equal if they refer to the exact same array in memory, at the same address.

---

That explains what happens, but how to fix it?

For traditional `class` reference items, you would have the `Car` type implement `IEquatable` and `IComparable`, and override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods. Yes... **all** of that or *none* of it. It is "dirty", but its what you needed to do.

For the newer `record` items I'm not really sure we have an idiomatic way to handle this situation yet. For the moment, I would revert to my old habits and try to do the old reference pattern.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP understands this, otherwise they wouldn't have suggested to *"define my own type like RecordArray : IEnumerable with overridden Equals & operators"*. Your answer might be helpful for future readers, though.

Comment: "*For the newer record items I'm not really sure we have an idiomatic way to handle this situation yet.*" -- define your own `Equals(Car other)` and `GetHashCode()` methods in the record. The compiler will generate code which calls `Equals(Car other)`